# Does Write send all bytes? (Serial Port)

Tags: c#

Does `Write` method of SerialPort write all bytes it was told to?
I have this code to send data via serial port.

```
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort(
              "COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            // Open the port for communications
            port.Open();

            // Write bytes
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world from PC");
            port.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            // Close the port
            port.Close();
```

If I send string "Hello" the device connected to my PC via serial port receives it well. If I send string "Hello world from PC"
it only receives
first 16 bytes instead of 19.
Is there a way I can verify in code that all bytes were sent? Or it is problem of the hardware which is connected via serial port?

Comment: Can you post your code on how you receive data??

Comment: OK...But then are you sure that that device is able to read ALL the bytes sent..? by looking at your code, the bytes / data should be sent without any problem..

Comment: Or try to check the CTS (Clear to send) before send..

Comment: @User2012384: I will try to check with hardware manufacturer

Comment: It could be useful if you specify what exactly the recieving device is. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723627/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-serialport-write-buffer

Comment: The Close() call will discard the bytes in the transmit buffer.  Do *not* repeatedly call Open/Close, the SerialPort class does not support that.  Just call Open at program start and only Close at program end.

Comment: Then sleeping for a while won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .Write is synchronous so all data is send before it returns. Anyway, 30 second timeout that you do would be more than enough, event if it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Normally all bytes are sent. Maybe the problem is at the receiving side.
To be sure that handshaking is turned off use this code, but I believe it is already the default:

```
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
```

I suspect the receiving side. It might be possible that the UART on the other side might not be fast enough to get the characters out of the buffer. Maybe you can try to add a small delays between parts of your message but that is only for troubleshooting, of course. Like so:

```
        // Write bytes for test purpose
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world from PC");
        port.Write(bytes, 0, 10);
        Thread.Sleep(100); // small delay
        port.Write(bytes, 10, 9); // next block
```

Comment: I mean, it should not be part of your final solution. Often embedded devices have small buffers and when they are not emptied fast enough, you loose characters. In the above code, the embedded device has some 100 ms to handle the incoming characters; that should be enough. Then the next bytes can come in. But you read 16 bytes...could that be the size of the buffer on the embedded side?

Comment: The H/W change is probably not needed. Only the bytes flow at an effective lower speed (baud rate stays the same, of course). You could even split it in even more writes with smaller size with smaller delays between it. But going back to the embedded device manufacturer might be the best way to get it going.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I write an array of 20 bytes to the serial port which is connected to a wireless transmitter. After sending all bytes I need to switch back to receive mode.
Therefore it is necessary to exactly know when all bytes are physically written out of the serial port.
Unfortunately this is impossible under Windows since the buffer queries do not return the status of the physical chip buffer.

The solution for me was to send the data async with serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync
and then calculate the amount of transmit time by multiplying the number of bytes with the baudrate:

```
serialPort.BaseStream.WriteAsync(buffer,0,buffer.length);
int waittime = (int)((double)buffer.length * (10/(double)baudrate) + some_reserve);
Thread.Sleep(waittime);
```

the "10" means that one byte consists of 10 bits